# How to run asp.net and vuejs on same localhost instance

Tags: asp.net, vue.js

i've developped and front end app with vue along with a backend with asp.net.Im currently trying to fetch data using axios but i get this error:"Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://localhost:50342/api/Albums/GetFeaturedAlbum' from origin 'http://localhost:8080' has been blocked by CORS policy: The 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header has a value 'http://www.yourSite.com' that is not equal to the supplied origin".
I understand the problem but i dont know the right way to solve it

Comment: Make sure the asp.net server sets an allow-origin header which contains the origin the request is coming from

Comment: If your are using Asp.net web api as backend your need to enable CORS. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/security/enabling-cross-origin-requests-in-web-api#enable-cors